# Is JavaFX actually embedded in Java SE? How do I use it this way?

Tags: java

I've heard that JavaFX is embedded in newer Java SE, and I decided to start using it because it has many useful things such as polylines and CSS support. When I tried to create an object of Polyline type, the class was not found, and the same happened with Node class. 
 How do I use JavaFX or where can I download it?

Edit 1:
 I'm using JDK 8u91 and Eclipse Java IDE(4.5.2).
 I've written this code ONLY to check whether the JavaFX is actually loaded:

```
package main;

public class Main{

    public static void Main(String[]){
        Polyline line = new Polyline();
    }
}
```

So, IDE says that Polyline cannot be resolved to a type.
I decided to compile and run this app to make sure it's not just mistake od IDE.

Edit 2:
 Added import javafx.scene.shape.*;
 Eclipse gives error:
  Access restriction: The type 'Polyline' is not API (restriction on required
  library 'C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_91\lib\ext\jfxrt.jar')
 Added some points to Polyline and then printed out **line** object.
 There were no compiling errors, but it's impossible to work when IDE spams you with error messages.

Comment: AFAIK it is embedded since Java 7. Which version are you using and how did you try to use it? Any [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: [JavaFX: Getting Started with JavaFX](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/get-started-tutorial/index.html)

Comment: Are you importing `javafx.scene.shape.Polyline`?

Comment: @Thomas Java FX 2 was available in Java 7, but not part of the Core.  As of Java 8, FX is part of the Core, which is one reason it now boasts Java Fx 8, instead of "3."

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted on behalf of the OP).*

Wow. I've forgot to set project's JRE to 1.8. Sorry for causing problems.